# Spring boot says it requires a certain bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is the userService class that requires a bean of type `com.example.repository.userRepository` that could not be found

```
package com.example.services;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.modal.User;
import com.example.repository.userRepository;


@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

 @Autowired
 private userRepository userRepository;


 public UserService() {
    super();
}

public UserService(userRepository userRepository)
 {
     this.userRepository = userRepository;
 }

 public void saveMyuser(User user) {
     userRepository.save(user);
 }
}
```

The error message reads :

> Consider defining a bean of type `'com.example.repository.userRepository'` in your configuration.

This is the repository:

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import com.example.modal.User;


public interface userRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Integer> {

}
```

this is the application class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TutorialProjectApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TutorialProjectApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Comment: add `@Service` annotation to the UserRepository class. It will instruct spring that he have to manage this class lifecycle, and it will be available for dependency injection

Comment: Can you share your application class (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) ?

Comment: add "@Component" to the UserRepository class or just go through about "@Componentscan" annotation.

Comment: Did you configure multiple jars for jpa like(mysql and hsql) or atleast one of the dependency in the those in your pom.xml or build.gradle or if you are using any other database other than hsql then have you configured the required properties in application.properties /application.yml.

Comment: Please check and let me know

Comment: Prasad i've configured jdbc driver in application.properties

Comment: Can you post exception stack trace?What about jar configuration in pom.xml ?

Comment: The solution is @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository"). thanks for trying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `userRepository` interface is outside of spring-boot default scanning i.e. package of that repository interface is not same or sub-package of the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. If so, you need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")` on your main class.

Update: 
After looking at your updated post, you need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")` to `TutorialProjectApplication` class

Answer (score 3):

Always keep the `@SpringBootApplication` main class outer package so that it will automatically scan all the subpackages.

In your case you have main class in package `com.example.demo;` but the repository in `package com.example.repository;` which are different packages.so spring boot is not able to find the repositories.

So you have to make spring boot aware of the repositories location.

So now you have 2 solutions.

1.Either put repository class in subpackges of Main class package.

2.Or use `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")` in main class.

Comment: `@Repository` isn't required.

Answer (score 2):

In your repository you need to annotate the class

```
@Repository
public interface userRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Integer> {

}
```

Comment: This is wrong, as CrudRepository a an annotation from Spring Data which itself will construct the bean definition of this repository. BTW you cannot annotate interfaces as `@Component`

Comment: I've been doing this fine for 3 years, not really sure why you can't.

Comment: Have you ever heard of stereotype annotations? Have a look here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Annotation-Programming-Model#stereotype-annotations

Comment: The solution is @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository"). thanks for trying